# Fatal error: Call to a member function getParentItem() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.8

I cannot do any more invoices, this error message appears in every order.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getParentItem() on a non-object in /home/design/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/invoice/view/items.phtml on line 50
```

Someone can help me to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like there is something wrong with the object you are trying to get the parent item from. Do you have some more code showing what the object consists of?